# Migrate org.joda.time to java.time

Tags: java, jodatime

I need to migrate also this code:

```
private int calculate(OffsetDateTime expirationDate) {
    return Seconds.secondsBetween(DateTime.now(), expirationDate).getSeconds();
  }
```

to this code:

```
private int calculate(OffsetDateTime expirationDate) {
    return Duration.between(OffsetDateTime.now(), expirationDate).getSeconds();
  }
```

`getSeconds` returns long. is there some better way to get int?

Comment: Define "better"? You can cast a long to an int, potentially losing values (or wrapping to negative values) or you could use `Math#toIntExact` which will throw an exception if the value cannot be represented with 32 bits.

Comment: ok, I will use casting

Comment: [`Math.toIntExact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact(long))? Otherwise no. The obvious alternative, `ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between()`, returns a `long` too.

Comment: By the way, I would use `toSeconds()` rather than `getSeconds`. The getter method was one of the few design flaws in *java.time* built into Java 8, a method exposing an implementation detail ([internally](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/Duration.java), a `Duration` is a pair of `long` integers, a count of seconds, & a count of nanos). Corrected in Java 9; `toSeconds` method follows the [naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html) per the other `to…` methods. So `getSeconds` should be deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

No; it is trivially imaginable that the gap, in seconds, between 2 OffsetDateTime objects is more than 2^31-1 seconds. (more than about 4 billion).

If you **know** it cannot possibly be such a large gap, just cast to int. The somewhat ugly 'int' cast is your visible sign in the code that somebody made an assumption that it won't be a problem. In other words, that cast is a GOOD thing.

If you're not quite sure and you want an exception instead, you have to program that. Fortunately, Java has a built-in [function for this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact(long)):

```
return java.lang.Math.toIntExact(Duration.between....);
```

That will throw if the returned amount is so large, casting it to an `int` would [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) the value.